# Run task while application is running

Tags: windows-10, windows-task-scheduler

Is there a way to run a windows task scheduler task while a process/application is running, and then stop that task when the application closes?

The task repeats itself every 2 minutes, until manually stopped, and I need it to start and stop as the process starts and stops.

Comment: You could schedule a process to run every how with Task Scheduler every often and tell it to start only when the other application process is running and to kill that process if that other process is not running. You'd have to have it check every so many minutes or seconds though so there should be a slight delay in either. You can do all this with a batch file. Tell me the name of the EXE that you want to check which is running, and the name of the EXE that you want to execute and kill depending on when or if the other process is running and I can send you the detail.

Comment: @1Fish_2Fish_RedFish_BlueFish Well I tried using batch file to start a task (using `schtasks`), but it doesn't seem to be triggering the `On Task Creation / Modify` trigger (on which I have the repeating command thing), so it only runs once, and then just stops.

Comment: Could you update your answer and show what you tried with batch so I understand your logic? If not, I need to know what process you want to check whether or not is running and what process you want to run; meaning the EXE names of the processes to run and check which is running or no. I know a way to do it a little differently that's reliable too. Tell me also what Windows you're running this on i.e. Win 10, 8, 7, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created 2 tasks, set the first task to do what I wanted it to do, but without a trigger, and then set the second task to start at login, repeat every 2 minutes to run a batch file.

The batch file I ran:

```
@echo off
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq YourProcess.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "YourProcess.exe">NUL

if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
  schtasks /RUN /TN "FirstTaskName">NUL
)
```

This checked if the process is running every 2 minutes, and if it is, run the task. (I got the code for checking if process is running from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162291/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-via-a-batch-script))

I also used a bat to exe converter to hide the cmd window that pops up.